# Why my query shows duplicate data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012

how I can stop this kind of repetition in my query ?

See I have 2 forms,

1. PersonalInfo
2. Trainings

Now only 1 personal record for 1 person but TrainingsCourses can be more than 1 record.

But problem is that with TrainingsCourses the personalInfo records also repeats which I don't want to.

SP:

```
SELECT PersonalInfo.pk_PersonalInfo_ID,
       PersonalInfo.PersonalInfoReligion,
       PersonalInfo.PersonalInfoPhoneResidence,
       PersonalInfo.PersonalInfoPhoneoffice,
       PersonalInfo.PersonalInfoNIC,
       PersonalInfo.PersonalInfoName,
       PersonalInfo.PersonalInfoMobile,
       PersonalInfo.PersonalInfoMaritalStatus,
       PersonalInfo.PersonalInfoGender,
       PersonalInfo.PersonalInfoFatherHusbandName,
       Convert(varchar, PersonalInfo.PersonalInfoEntryDateTime, 106),
       PersonalInfo.PersonalInfoEmailAddress,
       PersonalInfo.PersonalInfoDomicile,
       Convert(varchar,PersonalInfo.PersonalInfoDOB, 106) AS PersonalInfoDOB,
       PersonalInfo.PersonalInfoComputerLiterate,
       PersonalInfo.PersonalInfoAddress,
       PersonalInfo.fk_WebUsers_PersonalInfo_UserID,
       PersonalInfoEmployeePicture,
       Qualification.AcademicQualification,
       Qualification.pk_Qualification_QualificationID,
       Qualification.fk_PersonalInfo_Qualification_PID,
       Qualification.QualificationGrade,
       Qualification.QualificationInstituteAddress,
       Qualification.QualificationInstituteName,
       Qualification.QualificationMajorSubjects,
       Qualification.QualificationPassingYear,
       Qualification.fk_PersonalInfo_Qualification_PID,
       TrainingsCourses.pk_TrainingsCourses_ID,
       TrainingsCourses.fk_PersonalInfo_TrainingsCourses_PID,
       TrainingsCourses.TrainingsCoursesCountry,
       TrainingsCourses.TrainingsCoursesCourseTitle,
       Convert(varchar, TrainingsCourses.TrainingsCoursesFromDate, 106) AS TrainingsCoursesFromDate,
       TrainingsCourses.TrainingsCoursesInstituteAddress,
       TrainingsCourses.TrainingsCoursesInstituteName,
       Convert(varchar, TrainingsCourses.TrainingsCoursesToDate, 106) AS TrainingsCoursesToDate
FROM PersonalInfo
INNER JOIN Qualification ON Qualification.fk_PersonalInfo_Qualification_PID= PersonalInfo.pk_PersonalInfo_ID
INNER JOIN TrainingsCourses ON TrainingsCourses.fk_PersonalInfo_TrainingsCourses_PID= PersonalInfo.pk_PersonalInfo_ID
WHERE PersonalInfo.pk_PersonalInfo_ID= @pk_PersonalInfo_ID
```

Comment: If person has more than 1 training, what output do you expect without duplicating  person data?

Comment: try adding `distinct`

Comment: It is not clear what sort of output you want to get here, please provide more detail.

Comment: @dotnetom then only Trainings/Courses should repeat, not PersonalInfo

Comment: Use 2 queries to get the personal info and trainings / courses separately

Comment: @Juventustech, you obviously join them, so how do you expect that PersonalInfo will not repeat? For each record of Trainings you will obviously get the PersonalInfo columns populated with the repeating data ... How do you expect several trainings of one person to look like in your result ... what do you expect to see in PersonalInfo?